# Issues with typeahead in angular

Tags: angularjs, typeahead

I am using typeahead with angular js and everything is working fine , expect one case.

Suppose I searched for something let say `test`which shows two results for test but instead of click on result either I clicked on text-box where I was typing or anywhere else on screen , then again if i type to search something then search is not working , the request is send to back-end and I am getting the response but that response not showing in front end as search result.

**My code :**

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control " name="search_title" ng-model="formData.search_title" required autocomplete="off" typeahead="state as state.name for state in searchStates($viewValue) | orderBy:name"  typeahead-loading="loading" typeahead-min-length="2" typeahead-wait-ms="100" typeahead-on-select='searchSelect($item, $model, $label)'>


$scope.searchStates = function(state){
          return $http({
            method : 'GET',
            url : '/search-state/?q='+state,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},

            }).then(function(response,status){
                return response.data;
                });

        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved when I changed the version of `ui-bootstrap-tpls` . Earlier I was using version `0.12.1` but when I changed it to `ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js` , eveything works fine. So may be this issue was due to wrong version.

**Use this**

```
  <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"></script>
```

**instead of**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.12.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
```